# How can I copy a column with formulas and paste those values in the same exact column using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, paste

```
Sheets("MoM").Select
Range("H2:H").Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

All I want to do is remove the VLOOKUP Formula by pasting the values within the same column starting at "H2" and ending at the last cell with a formula in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With Worksheets("MoM").Range("H2", Worksheets("MoM").Range("H65536").End(xlUp))
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Nice, I was keeping it simple, but I like how you did the `.End(xlUp)` in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you have not working?  If you want to remove the formula, but keep the values, a super quick way is to just set the range equal to itself:

```
Dim lastRow&
With Sheets("MoM")
     lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,8).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value = .Range("H2:H" & lastRow).Value
End With
```

Comment: It keeps saying "Application-defined or object defined error"

Comment: For some reason it is bringing an error still...is there another way to select the entire column and paste the values over the formula?

Comment: @Hags - Did you post all of your code? If not, please post the rest (edit into your OP). What line does it show that error on? Do you have a sheet called "MoM"?

Comment: `.Range("H2:H")` does not have an end row.

Comment: @ScottCraner - D'oh! Fixed, although it will do the entire Column H. (I'll edit to include a `lastRow` variable).

Comment: Sheets("MoM").Select

Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-7],'Table Array'!C[-7]:C[2],8,FALSE)"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillSeries

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Comment: I would not bother, when assigning the values it does not take that much more time to simply `.Range("H2:H" & .Rows.Count).Value`